# Задача с ориентированным графом

Tags: c++, графы

Нужно найти и вывести все минимальные циклы в ориентированном графе, который задан матрицей смежности, подскажите оптимальное решения данной задачи, сам уже долго придумать не могу, алгоритмов в интернете толком тоже нету

Comment: Открываете любую книгу по алгоритмам, главу про ориентированные графы, раздел про поиск циклов.

Answer (score 1):

### Вам поможет поиск в ширину.

Запускаете [поиск в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83), как только "волновой фронт" соприкоснётся сам с собой - вы нашли минимальный цикл.

Также почитайте про [волновой алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9B%D0%B8), он по сути является переформулировкой поиска в ширину, вы запускаете волну, как только она соприкоснулась сама с собой - это минимальный цикл.

Если вам нужны все минимальные  циклы - в момент самосоприкосновения волны надо обработать не одно касание, а все.